# Unit testing for Jfreecharts

Tags: unit-testing, jfreechart, mockito

I am constructing a simple linechart using JFreechart API.. Can anyone let me know how to unit test it using mockito. I am still kind of new to do unit testing framework. Dont really know how it works

```
public LineChart(String applicationTitle, String chartTitle) {

    super(applicationTitle);
    // Create the dataset
    CategoryDataset dataset = new DataSet().createDataLineSet();        
    JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset, chartTitle);
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CHART_WIDTH, 
            CHART_HEIGHT));
    setContentPane(chartPanel);

}

/**
 * Creates a sample chart
 * 
 * @param dataset
 *            ,the chartTitle
 * 
 * @return The chart.
 */
public JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset dataset, String chartTitle) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // create the chart
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(chartTitle, // chart
                                                            // title
            categoryAxisLabel, // category axis label
            valueAxisLabel, // value axis label
            dataset, // data
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // chart orientation
            true, // include legend?
            true, // include tooltips?
            false // URLs?
            );
    return chart;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you've structured it, this is a particularly hard class to unit test, and I'm not sure how much value unit testing would provide. Is this code for a school or work project with a "unit test all your code" directive?

First, a clarification based on your tags: Mockito is not a unit testing framework.

- [junit](/questions/tagged/junit) is a unit testing framework that allows you to write classes with methods that exercise classes. Using exceptions, as well as calls to [`Assert.assertEquals`, `Assert.assertTrue`, and `Assert.fail`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Assertions) (for instance) you can write tests with minimal boilerplate. Reading [JUnit's Getting Started page](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Getting-started) may help.
- [mockito](/questions/tagged/mockito) is a *mocking framework*, which allows you create [*mocks* and *stubs*](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) of objects and verify that you're system under test is interacting with its collaborators correctly. Though it's preferable to unit test just by checking the return value of a method call or the state of the system after your test, certain classes require interaction with external systems. The first few numbered items of [the Mockito documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html) may help.

At least three things make your class hard to test using mocks and JUnit:

- Your system under test is directly calling constructors. This gives you very little opportunity to substitute in simpler implementations or mocks for test.
- The collaborator you're interacting with (JFreeChart API) is designed for GUIs. It can be hard to test GUI-oriented classes in a headless, reproducible way, which are two typical aspects of unit tests.
- The collaborator is third-party software, which can be dangerous to mock. Mocking relies on some implementation details (like whether methods are `public` or `final`) that can be dangerous for code that's not directly under your control.

Remember also that it is an anti-pattern to test the implementation—unit tests are designed to check that your code produces the correct results. Looking at the code that you posted, I'm not sure what I would test there.

On the other hand, if you have a separate part of the project that loads and processes numeric data to feed into your chart, it would be very straightforward and useful to produce a JUnit test that takes in data from a sample file, runs it through the loader/processor you write, and ensures that it produces the correct numbers that you've worked out and confirmed by hand. The continued passing of that test is some guarantee that your code still works as expected, even if the implementation of your loader/processor were to change.